# Reverse order of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, order-theory

When we think of an ordered structure with an order $\le$ we assume there is an opposite order $\le^{op}$ as well:

- $a \le^{op} b \iff b \le a$.

I would suggest this is a fundamental principle for all ordered structures:
If a structure is ordered one way $(\le)$ it is also ordered the opposite way $(\le^{op})$.

The reverse order principle works on the simplest algebraic structures:

- An ordered set with a unary operation $f(a) = b$:
  $a \le b \implies f(a) \le f(b)$ or
  $a \le^{op} b \implies f(a) \le^{op} f(b)$ for any $a,b$;
- An ordered semigroup with a binary operation $f(a,b) = c$:
  $a \le b \implies f(a,c) \le f(b,c) \land f(c,a) \le f(c,b)$ or
  $a \le^{op} b \implies f(a,c) \le^{op} f(b,c) \land f(c,a) \le^{op} f(c,b)$ for any $a,b,c$;
- An ordered group (same as an ordered semigroup).

Now, let's apply the principle to an ordered ring $R(+,\cdot,0,1,\le)$.

- The compatibility rule for addition is fine:
  $a \le b \implies a + c \le b + c \land c + a \le c + b$ or
  $a \le^{op} b \implies a + c \le^{op} b + c \land c + a \le^{op} c + b$ for any $a,b,c$;
- But what about the compatibility rule for multiplication?
  $0 \le a \land 0 \le b \implies 0 \le a \cdot b$ or
  $0 \le^{op} a \land 0 \le^{op} b \implies 0 \le^{op} a \cdot b$.

Checking the last statement on the ring of integers with the regular order and operations:
Taking $a = -1$ and $b = -1$: $0 \le^{op} -1 \land 0 \le^{op} -1 \implies 0 \le^{op} (-1) \cdot (-1) = 1$ (false).

It looks like the reverse order principle does not work on rings:
If a ring is ordered one way $(\le)$ it may not be ordered the opposite way $(\le^{op})$.

Is this correct?
If yes, why do we ignore the reverse order principle for rings?
Are there (non-standard) definitions of an ordered ring that accept the opposite order?

Comment: $a \ge b$ is almost *always* just notation for $b \le a$. I'm not sure why you'd expect multiplication to behave like that. It's of course true that $a \ge 0 \land b \ge 0 \implies ab \ge 0$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I am asking about the opposite (reverse, inverse, converse, etc.) order, not about different notations of the same order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Inverse_and_order_dual

Comment: @AlexC I think I'm on the same page as what you're asking, but the comment above appears to be correct: you reversed both the direction of the symbol *and* the order of the things compared, effectively cancelling out the change.   What I'd expect you to write is $a\leq b \iff b\preceq a$, to give a second symbol to the new order.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you're asking a little better now. Probably the only such definition is $R$ is ordered by $\preceq$ if the additive group of $R$ is ordered by $\preceq$. As soon as you introduce rules about multiplication, that you expect to work usefully with $\Bbb Z$, I think you kind of have to give rise to the notion of "the positive cone" of positive integers. These will not be preserved by reversing the order.

Comment: @rschwieb I am following the Wikipedia: "The inverse (or converse) of a partial order relation $\le$ is the converse of $\le$. Typically denoted $\ge$..."

Comment: @AlexC If you want to write it that way, you'd write $a\leq b\iff a\geq b$, but since that is a little confusing it would be better to use $a\leq b\iff a\succeq b$.  You can reverse the direction of the symbol, but you *don't want to reverse the order of the things compared.*. That's the problem in your first line....

Comment: @AlexC I see that line in wikipedia, but I don't believe it. The "opposite" relation for any relation just takes the arrow between objects and turns it around. It does not also *swap the objects*.  I'm inclined to think someone made a mistake.

Comment: I've thought really hard about it, and if it is not a mistake, it is just an outrageously confusing choice of notation.  Added to my answer explaining why.

Comment: I replaced the symbol $"\ge"$ with $"\le^{op}"$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reverse order isn't consistent with the compatibility axioms of the order with the ring structure.

Suppose you reverse the order in a ring with identity.

Then $0\leq^{op} -1$, and from the multiplicative axiom $0\leq^{op} (-1)(-1)=1$.

From the additive axiom and $0\leq^{op} -1$, adding $1$ to both sides would yield $1\leq^{op} 0$, and from the previous deduction $1=0$.  Presumably this isn't the case for the ring you started with, so you have a contradiction.

---

Note: I think what's written at the wiki link you cited causes considerable confusion. In my opinion, it's better written at [opposite category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_category) where they write "$x ≤^{op} y$ if and only if $y ≤ x$."  I believe this was *the intent* of what's written at the partial order wiki, because partial orders can be viewed as categories, and the reverse order ought to be the opposite category.

I think the reason what's written at the order wiki is confusing is that most people will interpret $a\leq b$ and $b\geq a$ as meaning *exactly the same thing*, that $b$ is the bigger thing.  But the whole point of the reverse order is to make big things small and small things big. If we were to follow in the notation suggested at the order wiki, we would say this in the opposite order "$b$ used to be the bigger one, so now in the new order $a$ is bigger, and I will write $b\geq a$."

If you just view the thing in between as a separator, and always read it as "the thing on the left is smaller" then it is a correct description of the reverse order. I just think it is *extremely* confusing to reverse both the inputs and the direction of the symbol.

Comment: I replaced the symbol $"\ge"$ with $"\le^{op}"$.

Comment: @AlexC Ok!   And I fixed my notation to line up with your change. Does what I'm saying about the incompatibility make sense, either way?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. And I think it is a huge flaw in the definition of an ordered ring. A correct definition should be consistent with the reverse order. I have some proposals in mind, but before asking about them I wanted to find if anyone else sees the issue.

Comment: I dunno, it seems unavoidable to me, from the perspective of "squares have to be positive."  But yeah, you could come up with some sort of quasi-order for rings.

Comment: @AlexC Or also you might consider replacing "order" with a notion of "between" to make it symmetrical.  So you'd have a "ring with betweenness"

Comment: @AlexC, it's certainly an interesting idea to make a definition of "ordered ring" that behaves this way. However I think it's pushing it to say that the current definition is flawed. You should be careful not to let aesthetics get in the way of the actual mathematics. The definition is the way that it is for a reason: it's useful. Currently, a ring ordering can be thought of as "less than". The notion of ordered ring has certainly proved itself useful - eg, any ordered field with the LUB property is isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ - so you can't just do away with the current definition.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you. I was a bit rhetorical about the flaw.